# How can I change the package name programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, refactoring

I was thinking about accessing the Manifest file from activity ,and change the package name,  is there any way to achieve that? or any other way to refactor the package name programmatically?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.refactoring"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Comment: just curious why anyone would want to do that?

Comment: package name is like a primary key, every app on google play is identified uniquely using package name so its not possible to change it programatically

Comment: @asloob i have an application that generates an APK , and this APK should be uploaded to the market , this APK generating is done programticly , so i need to change that programticly as well so the user just have to upload the APK to the market ,as the user dosn't have any programing background

Comment: @user1283633 You are creating an android app, which creates another another app ?

Comment: @asloob yes and it works fine , except for this issue 
it generates another application with different config, and this config is changed by a user wizard , its an app generator app

Comment: @user1283633 sounds cool. but its difficult to say how we can change the package name, without knowing the 'apk generation' process you are using. You can extract the .apk file to get the Manifest and if possible edit the file and repackage the apk.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You can change it at compile time, by editing the manifest file, but you cannot change it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms Not possible.. actually by the way.. package name represents the class folder structure..